# GridView page numbers appearing in separate columns far apart

Tags: css, asp.net, gridview, paging

I am using a gridview as below. Somehow the page numbers appear in separate columns. I want them to appear together in the center. How do I bring the page numbers together in the center?

```
 <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" Width="100%" OnRowCommand="GridView1_RowCommand" CssClass="GridStyle" AllowPaging="true" AllowSorting="True" AutoGenerateColumns="False" BorderColor="Black" OnPageIndexChanging="GridView1_PageIndexChanging"> 

 <PagerStyle Font-Underline="false" BorderColor="White" BorderStyle="None" BorderWidth="0"  />
```

[image]

CSS

```
.GridStyle {
table-layout: auto;
border: 1px solid black;
background-color: White;
font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
font-size: 12px;
/*border-collapse: collapse;
margin-bottom: 0px;*/
}

.GridStyle tr {
    border: 1px solid black;
    color: black;
    background-color: #E5E4F2;
    height: 25px;
}


.GridStyle th {
    background-color: white;
    border: none;
    text-align: left;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 15px;
    padding: 4px;
    color: black;
}


.GridStyle tr th a, .GridStyle tr th a:visited {
    color: red;
}

.GridStyle tr th, .GridStyle tr td table tr td {
    color: #484585;
    border: 1px solid black;
}

.GridStyle td {
    border-bottom: 1px solid black;
    padding: 2px;
}
```

Like this

Answer (score 1):

Your CSS class of gridViewPager may be sizing the page number elements against the  table width.

Review gridViewPager, particularly in regards to any `width: 100%;`.

Comment: I am sorry, I forgot to remove the class from the code. Actually there's no gridViewPager class.

Comment: Have you tried removing or editing your <PagerStyle> tag?

Comment: Tried removing it, no difference. Editing.. I don't know what else to try.

Comment: Unfortunately, I am just making guesses at what might work, I have no idea how the surrounding CSS elements interact. Does setting a fixed width (e.g. 'width: 256px;') and 'margin: 0 auto;' give you centered pagination?

Comment: I had set width for all table elements to 100%. Setting it to auto worked for me. Thanks for your help though.

Answer (score 1):

The pager in a GridView is a nested table. So it is probably inheriting a `100%` width property from a parent element.

In HTML, the pager looks like this.

```
<tr>
    <td colspan="8">
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td><span>1</span></td>
                <td><a href="javascript:__doPostBack(&#39;ctl00$mainContentPane$GridView1&#39;,&#39;Page$2&#39;)">2</a></td>
                <td><a href="javascript:__doPostBack(&#39;ctl00$mainContentPane$GridView1&#39;,&#39;Page$3&#39;)">3</a></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </td>
</tr>
```

You can either fix the inheriting or give the pager it's own class.

```
<PagerStyle CssClass="pagerCssClass" Font-Underline="false" BorderColor="White" BorderStyle="None" BorderWidth="0" />
```

Comment: Actually I figured out that it was inheriting table element width. I changed it to auto and it worked. Thanks for your answer though.